# Rails: Sum of values in all Transactions that belong_to an Activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- Live site: http://iatidata.heroku.com
- Github: https://github.com/markbrough/IATI-Data
- Based on aid information released through the IATI Registry: iatiregistry.org

I'm a bit of a Rails n00b so sorry if this is a really stupid question.

There are two key Models in this app:

- Activity - which contains details
  such as recipient country, funding
  organisation
- Transaction - which contains details such as how much money (value) was committed or disbursed (transaction_type), when, to whom, etc.

All Transactions nest under an Activity. Each Activity has multiple Transactions. They are connected together by activity_id. has_many :transactions and belongs_to :activity are defined in the Activity and Transaction Models respectively.

So: all of this works great when I'm trying to get details of transactions for a single activity - either when looking at a single activity (activity->show) or looping through activities on the all activities page (activity->index). I just call

```
@activities.each do |activity|
    activity.transactions.each do |transaction|
        transaction.value # do something like display it
    end
end
```

But what I now really want to do is to get the sum of all transactions for all activities (subject to :conditions for the activity).

What's the best way to do this? I guess I could do something like:

```
@totalvalue = 0
@activities.each do |activity|
    activity.transactions.each do |transaction|
        @totalvalue = @totalvalue + transaction.value
    end 
end
```

... but that doesn't seem very clean and making the server do unnecessary work. I figure it might be something to do with the model...?! sum() is another option maybe?

This has partly come about because I want to show the total amount going to each country for the nice bubbles on the front page :)

Thanks very much for any help!

**Update:**

Thanks for all the responses! So, this works now:

```
@thiscountry_activities.each do |a|
    @thiscountry_value = @thiscountry_value + a.transactions.sum(:value)
end
```

But this doesn't work:

```
@thiscountry_value = @thiscountry_activities.transactions.sum(:value)
```

It gives this error:

```
undefined method `transactions' for #<Array:0xb5670038>
```

Looks like I have some sort of association problem. This is how the models are set up:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :activity
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :policy_markers
    has_and_belongs_to_many :sectors
    has_many :transactions
end
```

I think this is probably quite a simple problem, but I can't work out what's going on. The two models are connected together via id (in Activity) and activity_id (in Transactions).

Thanks again!

Comment: See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum or try the ruby inject() method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use Active Record's awesome `sum` method, available for classes:

```
Transaction.sum(:value)
```

Or, like you want, associations:

```
activity.transactions.sum(:value)
```

Comment: Sorry, I keep accidentally hitting Enter rather than Shift+Enter...  

Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I think this is right, but something weird is happening. This works:    
@thiscountry_activities.each do |a|   
 @thiscountry_value = @thiscountry_value + a.transactions.sum(:value)    
end    
    
This doesn't:     
@thiscountry_value =   @thiscountry_activities.transactions.sum(:value)     
     
It gives the error:     
undefined method `transactions' for #<Array:0xb53e361c>     
     
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let the database do the work:

```
@total_value = Transaction.sum(:value)
```

This gives the total for all transactions. If you have some activities already loaded, you can filter them this way:

```
@total_value = Transaction.where(:activity_id => @activities.map(&:id)).sum(:value)
```

You can do it with one query:

```
@total_value = Transaction.joins(:activity).where("activities.name" => 'foo').sum(:value)
```

Answer (score 1):

My code was getting pretty messy summing up virtual attributes.  So I wrote this little method to do it for me.  You just pass in a collection and a method name as a string or symbol and you get back a total.  I hope someone finds this useful.

```
def vsum collection, v_attr # Totals the virtual attributes of a collection
  total = 0
  collection.each { |collect| total += collect.method(v_attr).call } 
  return total
end

# Example use

total_credits = vsum(Account.transactions, :credit)
```

Of course you don't need this if :credit is a table column.  You are better off using the built in ActiveRecord method above.  In my case i have a :quantity column that when positive is a :credit and negative is a :debit.  Since :debit and :credit are not table columns they can't be summed using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you would like to have the sum of all values of the transaction table. You can use SQL for that. I think it will be faster than doing it the Ruby way.

> select sum(value) as transaction_value_sum from transaction;

Comment: Yeah almost, except that only where they are part of `@activities[:conditions=>@conditions]`. Maybe SQL would be sensible anyway, but the tricky bit is from the association with the Activity I think.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
@total_value = activity.transactions.sum(:value)
```

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I think this is right, but something weird is happening. **This works:** `@thiscountry_activities.each do |a| @thiscountry_value = @thiscountry_value + a.transactions.sum(:value) end` **This doesn't:** `@thiscountry_value = @thiscountry_activities.transactions.sum(:value)` **It gives the error:** `undefined method `transactions' for #<Array:0xb53e361c>` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you setting the value of `@thiscountry_activities`?

Comment: **In the view:**
`@thiscountry_activities = Activity.all(:conditions=>@conditions_countries_codes)`
      
I set @activities in the controller in a similar way, and it doesn't like that either. The @conditions are mostly from `params`, so that it only shows the activities that conform to whatever filters the user has added.

Comment: @Mark: The association for transactions in on a SINGLE activity, not on many of them. You're calling `transactions` on the Array representing all the `Activity` objects here.